# AnjularJs Material $mdDialog closeTo condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, mddialog

I have a modal but need to target the closeTo event depending if cancel is pressed or if 'Add To Basket' is pressed. I currently have this

```
         vm.modal = $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'app/views/shop/viewOfferModal.html',
            controller: 'viewOfferController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            closeTo: angular.element(document.querySelector('#basketicon')),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: false
          });
```

but i cannot seem to change depending on the users action 
When closing the modal If cancel is pressed I need to close it normally
$mdDialog.cancel(); - by the line targetEvent: ev,

But if an action button is pressed(and there is only one button - 'Add to basket') I need the modal to closeTo the basket id.

So I need to use this line somewhere in the modal I'm guessing to change the modal property 
closeTo: angular.element(document.querySelector('#basketicon')),

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: here is the same issue https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1786